# C program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault at matrix-multiplication?

Tags: c, matrix, malloc, segmentation-fault

*Yes, I've read through the questions like this, but none of them proved useful in my problem.* My program has a problem with a function that has been working perfectly in another one.

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. _int_malloc (av=0x7ffff7dd8e40, bytes=32) at malloc.c:4703 4703    malloc.c: No such file or directory.

That's the error I recieve.

And here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void endl()
{
  printf("\n\n");
}

void loadVector(FILE *infile, double *vector, int col)
{
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<col;i++)
  {
    fscanf(infile,"%lf",&vector[i]);
  }
  printf("vector read...\n");
}

void printVec(double *vect, int run)
{
  int k;
  for(k=0;k<run;k++)
  {
   printf("%.2f ",vect[k]);
  }
}

double* duplic(double* matr, double *vect, double *sol,  int col, int  row)
{
  int k, l;
  for(k=0;k<row;k++)
  {
    for(l=0;l<col;l++)
    {
      sol[k] += matr[col*k+l] * vect[l];
    }
  }
  return sol;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  endl();
  printf("=== ===");
  endl();

  if(argc!=3)
  {
    perror("not enough arguments");
    endl();
    return 1;
  }

  char ins[300];
  char *cut;
  int row=0, col=0, rnr = 1, index = 0;
  double temp;
  double *mat = NULL;
  double *vec = NULL;
  double *res = NULL;

  FILE *in;
  in = fopen(argv[1], "r");

  while(fgets(ins,sizeof(ins),in) != NULL)
  {
      col = 0;
      cut = strtok(ins," ");
      while(cut != NULL)
      {
        col++;
        sscanf(cut,"%lf",&temp);
        if(mat==NULL)
         {
            mat = malloc(sizeof(temp));
            *mat = temp;
         }
         else
         {
            rnr ++;
            mat = realloc(mat,sizeof(mat)*rnr);
            index = rnr - 1;
            *(mat+index)=temp;
         }
        cut = strtok(NULL," ");
    }
    row ++;
 }

fclose(in);

printf("Matrix read...");
endl();

printf("Printing matrix: ");
endl();

int i, j;
for(i=0;i<row;i++)
{
   for(j=0;j<col;j++)
   {
      printf("%.2f ",mat[col*i+j]);
   }
   printf("\n");
}
endl();

// printf("rows: %i\tcols: %i\n",row,col);

vec = malloc(sizeof(col));

FILE *inv;
inv = fopen(argv[2],"r");
loadVector(inv,vec,col);

endl();
printVec(vec,col);
endl();

res = malloc(sizeof(row)); 
res = duplic(mat,vec,res,col,row);

printf("Solution-vector calculated...");
endl();
printf("\nSolution vector:");
endl();

printVec(res,row);

endl();

free(mat);
free(vec);
free(res);
fclose(inv);

printf("Exitting\n");
return 0;
}
```

The program is a matrix - vector multiplication one, which reads an unknown sized matrix and a matching vector (*also, if you can offer a better way to read a random-length line with a better code, I'd be happy*).
The problem comes at the multiplication code - though it should be working, as it is with another program I wrote where the size is fix.
So it reads the matrix and vector nicely, then gives the segfault.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You should do some debugging - Valgrind would be an excellent help here (assuming it's an option on your platform).

Comment: Funnily enough, when I was running it with Valgrind it gave no problems and ran as intended. When I ran normally, it died again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write `sizeof(col)`, but `col` is an integer, which means your `vec` array will always be allocated `sizeof(int)` bytes of memory (which is typically 4 bytes but will depend on your architecture). If you want a double array with col number of doubles, you want to use `malloc(sizeof(double) * col)` to allocate the right amount of bytes.

I suspect the same issue is occurring for your `res` array. It might work in some cases where the space after the space you allocated is still available for write, in which case the computer doesn't complain, since malloc'ed memory is all in the heap. However, if it so happens that you try to write to a protected or reserved section of memory after the malloc'ed block (which is too small), the OS will throw a SegFault.

Comment: Aaaand that fixed it... damn. Thanks for the quick and useful answer!

Comment: No problem, you might want to look at some of the other malloc's in your code. I think your res needs to be `col * row * sizeof(double)`.

Comment: "4 bytes of memory (the size of an integer)" 1) There are various integer types. Assuming you mean `int`: this is not guaranteed. And `int` can have any size from 1 byte.

Comment: @Olaf updated my answer, integer referring to the standard integer type `int`

Comment: I don't see the relevant part being updated. And what is a standard machine? The C standard does not guarantee this. And most architectures (units sold and families) use 16 bit `int`.

Comment: If we consider OP has the other `malloc` calls correct, it looks like a typo.

Comment: @Olaf _int can have any size from 1 byte._ You check `INT_MAX`.

Comment: @Olaf _It shall be equal or greater in magnitude_ (INT_MAX : +32767)

Comment: Forgot, sorry :)
also, the size of res is fine as it is, as it isn't a matrix but vector

Comment: @NicoleJudge hmm, just remember `sizeof(row)` will also return `sizeof(int)`, which may not be exactly what you want, but use your own discretion :)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Which requires **at least** 16 bits. So what?

Comment: @Olaf You said that _int can have any size from 1 byte_

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: What's wrong about that? Please provide a reference to the standard a byte is 8 bits!

Comment: @Olaf In that way I can understand. But for people who are not familiar with it, I think that you should choose words. I am sorry for bothering you.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: I choose my words very carefully. And they are correct. It is not my fault if you assume byte == 8 bits. I'm just not for spoon-feeding. Better teach fishing than give a fish - you know.

Comment: @Olaf I do not think that you taught fishing.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: No, but I try to encourage **thinking** which is way more important. Problem is there are way too many spoon-feeders here.

Comment: @FelixGuo yes, I changed it to sizeof(double)*row :) thank you again for the help!